# Field Collection fields not displaying

Tags: entities

I have been running into some trouble with displaying Field Collections. I have a content type (products) that has a field collection called packages. Randomly I would notice that sometimes the field collection fields wouldn't display. Today they have stopped displaying and aren't coming back.

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. All the fields are set to display in the field collection display settings. Even when I just look at the node view page they aren't displayed there.

I was curious if anyone can help with this issue?

EDIT: It appears that enabling and disabling modules (doesn't matter which one) fixes this and the fields display. Not sure what triggers it to break again though.

Comment: Sounds like cache problems due to slow database connection. Try to check your site in local environment.

Comment: It sounds like Oleg Sherbakov hit it on the head. The DB has been extremely slow. I haven't run into the issue again but will follow Antonello's advice if I do. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your drupal watchdog logs? What's your php memory limit?

Answer (score 0):

You can at least start debugging the issue using the devel module: it can tell you if the field collection entity is loaded (so, a render problem) or not.
Also it can gives you the id of the entity for further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the field collection item, if you get the expected result that means there is nothing wrong with your field collection. Just make sure the field collection field/entity is not hidden in the view mode setting of the node.